# Representation of a C*-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a  C*-algebra. It seems that for given an *-representation $\pi$ of $A$, there is unique central projection $z_{\pi}$ in $A^{**}$ such that $\pi$ is just (unitary equivalent to) $\rho_z$ where 
$$\rho_z:A\to A^{**} : a\to az$$

It means that there is a one to one correspondence between Rep($A$), the equivalence class of *-representations of $A$, and $Z(A^{**})$, the set of all central projectionas in $A^{**}$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would like to be sure that $\pi\simeq \rho_z$.

Comment: Your notation doesn't completely make sense to me. The conclusion is false, however; let $A = K(H)$ and $A^{**} = B(H)$. The only central projections in $B(H)$ are $0$ and $I$, but $K(H)$ has lots of inequivalent representations --- one of each multiplicity.